# Real time data fetching from mysql using Axios in react js

Tags: real-time, infinite-loop, use-effect

I am new to react and I'm having some challenges, I want to have real time updating ui using data (complex json object) fetched from a mysql database using axios in react. I was using useEffect to handle the UI rerender however I am having challenges because its causing infinite rerendering, the json data is too complex for the useEffect dependency array. Which approach should I use, will sockets help?

```
useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true;

        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/update_irrigation', {
            sql: sql
        }).then(res => {
            if (isMounted) setIrrigator(res.data.results);
        })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        return () => { isMounted = false };
    })
```

here is a sample of the json object array, which is dynamic :

```
[
    {
        "ID": 9,
        "Sensor_1": 9,
        "Sensor_2": 65,
        "Sensor_3": 43,
        "Sensor_4": 35,
        "Sensor_5": 55,
        "Sensor_6": 56,
        "Sensor_7": 12,
        "Sensor_8": 32,
        "Sensor_9": 90,
        "Sensor_10": 99,
        "Solenoid_1": "open",
        "Solenoid_2": "open",
        "Solenoid_3": "closed",
        "Solenoid_4": "closed",
        "Solenoid_5": "open",
        "Time": "2022-02-17T14:27:49.000Z"
    },
    {
        "ID": 5,
        "Sensor_1": 40,
        "Sensor_2": 3,
        "Sensor_3": 4,
        "Sensor_4": 12,
        "Sensor_5": 43,
        "Sensor_6": 56,
        "Sensor_7": 12,
        "Sensor_8": 32,
        "Sensor_9": 90,
        "Sensor_10": 99,
        "Solenoid_1": "open",
        "Solenoid_2": "open",
        "Solenoid_3": "closed",
        "Solenoid_4": "closed",
        "Solenoid_5": "open",
        "Time": "2022-02-17T05:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

O you should add an empty array ([]) immediately after the return function that should stop multiple re-rendering

useEffect=()=>{
Do something,
return function {}
, []}